# Matching numbers in the URL path directly following the domain name using a rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’m trying to clean up our SEO by catching non-canonical URLs that are being indexed by Google.

Here is a sample of one of our non-canonical URLs

```
https://www.umpqua.edu/184-about-ucc/facts-visitor-info?start=1
```

I can catch it with this RegEx (see below) in the HTACCESS file but it also disabled other URLs that I want to work. It catches URLs with `/NUMBER-`. The number is two-three characters in length.

```
/([0-9]{2,3})-
```

So I'm trying to make it more unique. I have tried this (below) without success. My hope is to catch URLs with `edu/NUMBER-`

```
(edu)/([0-9]{2,3})-
```

I have also tried

```
(edu/)([0-9]{2,3})-
```

Here is my full HTACCESS entry:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(edu)/([0-9]{2,3})-$
RewriteRule .* index.php [G]
```

Comment: "edu" is part of the host name, which you wouldn't normally bother matching in a rule, because it will be the same for all URLs on your site. Meanwhile, surrounding a pattern with `^` and `$` means "must match this exactly" rather than "must contain this". Can you give an example of a URL that the current rule matches when it shouldn't, so we can help you come up with a new rule?

Comment: To "clean up your SEO" you should be redirecting the "non-canonical" URL to the canonical URL. However, your rather general regex would suggest that these URLs aren't simply "non-canonical", but are wholly invalid? What response is currently being served for these requests?

Comment: MrWhite - Yes. I would have to say these URLs are more invalid than non-canonical. Currently, our website uses Joomla and it generates URLs from its internal categorization (invalid) in addition to pages generated from menu items (canonical).

Comment: IMSoP - adding "edu" is just me trying make the RegEx more selective. So when I was using this expression /([0-9]{2,3})- it worked well except it also matched with this url. https://www.umpqua.edu/component/weblinks/weblink/239-external-links/10-student-account?Itemid=488&task=weblink.go but it should not have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> adding "edu" is just me trying make the RegEx more selective. So when I was using this expression `/([0-9]{2,3})-` it worked well except it also matched with this url. `/component/weblinks/weblink/239-external-links/…` but it should not have.

The significant thing about `edu` is that it is before the start of the URL-path. (But it's not part of the URL-path, it is the end part of the `Host` header.) In that case, just anchor the regex to the start of the URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{2,3}- - [G]
```

This needs to go near the top of the root `.htaccess` file.

`\d` is just short for `[0-9]`. Note there are 3 arguments in the above directive, separated by *spaces*:

1. `^\d{2,3}-` ... The *pattern* that matches against the URL-path
2. `-` ... The *substitution* string (in this case a single hyphen)
3. `[G]` ... The *flags*. In this case `G` for `gone` (short for `R=410`).

The above will serve a "410 Gone" for any URL-path that starts with 2 or 3 digits followed by a hyphen. There is a single hyphen in the *substitution* string to explicitly indicate "no substitution". Using `index.php` here is superfluous since it is ignored.

Note that there is no slash prefix on the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* when used in `.htaccess`.

You do not need a separate *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) - the comparison can more easily/efficiently be performed in the `RewriteRule` directive itself.

So the above will block `/184-about-ucc/facts-visitor-info?start=1` but not `/component/weblinks/weblink/239-external-links/...`, since the 3 digits in the second URL do not occur at the *start* of the URL-path.

Comment: Yes. I believe this ended up working. I was able to plug in the RegEx into Google Analytics and it gave me a report of all the matches. I verified that the matches were invalid URLs. I hope this ends up helping a lot of other Joomla users.